# Trigger downstream jenkins job when a job fails N times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need to start a downstream job in jenkins when the current job fails N number (say 3) times in a row. Is there a plugin to achieve this?
If not, Any other way I can achieve this?